# Child's styling to the bottom of itself within an overflowing parent element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a parent that has it's overflow-y property set to auto.

```
#parent {
position: relative;

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Then I have a child element that is larger than the window, it's overflowing with the parent, but the child element's styling isn't overflowing.

How do I make the child's styling overflow with itself?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like that?

```css
#parent {
position: relative;

overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
}

#child{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#child div {
  width: 120%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
    <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, qui sapiente, architecto minima voluptatibus illo pariatur necessitatibus doloremque, officia odio nesciunt quod beatae molestias autem aliquam mollitia tenetur! Nisi, soluta!
      
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas illum iure perspiciatis sint laudantium laborum vero ipsum, mollitia possimus consequuntur odio ullam veniam laboriosam culpa voluptatem neque, suscipit rem! Laboriosam.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consectetur placeat architecto dolores expedita quod ad? Praesentium quibusdam commodi cumque natus quos quam eius animi et reprehenderit tempora, ea, voluptas repellendus.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No quite what I was looking for, but my solution was just to use height: auto, thanks for the help though.